# get the ssid and the password of the hotspot android 8.0 and higher

Tags: android, passwords, hotspot, ssid

hello i try to get the  ssid and the password of the hotspot. i use in the method below and its work for android below to 8.
but in android 8.0 its throw exption , i read that i need to get some premisiion 
permission:android.permission.OVERRIDE_WIFI_CONFIG.
but we cant get this premission

```
   Method[] methods = m_wifiManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method m : methods) {
        if (m.getName().equals("getWifiApConfiguration")) {
            try {
                m_wifiConf = (WifiConfiguration) m.invoke(m_wifiManager);
                message = m_wifiConf.SSID + '/' + m_wifiConf.preSharedKey + '/';
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this relates to your approach with reflection, but as of Android 8.1 you need to have at least `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission and location services enabled in order to use [getConnectionInfo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#getconnectioninfo) (see [getScanResults()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#getScanResults())).

Anyway, that won't get you access to the wifi password.

As for the `OVERRIDE_WIFI_CONFIG` permission, it is [defined](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/bd4ae82f66d3b1af0b90f2bc533d8147bcc91beb/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml#L1402) as

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.OVERRIDE_WIFI_CONFIG"
android:protectionLevel="signature|privileged" />
```

This means that your app has to be signed by a platform key or to be added to the privileged [whitelist](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/perms-whitelist) in order to use this permission.